# Calculating the comparison wise error rate for multiple hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

In the new edition of ISLR by James et al, I was reading chapter 13 on multiple hypothesis testing, and in the following picture from the book, they note that the type I error rate is controlled at level $\alpha = 0.05$ by setting $\alpha_{S} = 0.002$ for a multiple hypothesis test of 5 contrasts (5 group means). The 5 means are referring to a dataset recording the monthly percentage excess returns for 2000 fund managers over $n = 50$ months where the hypothesis test involves the first 5 fund managers' returns. I am assuming this value of $0.002$ is the comparison wise type I error rate for each individual test. How is this value computed in regards to Scheffe's test or how does Scheffe's test compute this comparison wise error rate?

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is an interesting question, but it helps the readers if you include a bit more information from the link in the body of the text. (Some people are scared/reluctant of clicking links). Also in this case I think even the picture from the book contains too little information to compute the specific number because the description of the data is on an earlier page.

Comment: It seems the key point here is that the 0.002 is computed by scheffe's method. You might want to ask a more specific question about how this method works. I guess the invisible part of the book has some info about that too, but if there is a concrete point in the explanation that you don't understand it makes sense to describe that in more detail in your question

Comment: You can find the critical value using Scheffe and then find its two tailed probability to get the p-Value threshold.